# Freeform Pro - Dynamic Recipient doesn't work. Page only refresh

Tags: solspace-freeform

I am using Freeform Pro 4.1.8 and my dynamic recipents doesn't work. Actually, my recipents output are okay but when I submit there are no errors and the page only refresh. This is what I have in my freeform:form tag

```
{exp:freeform:form
          form_id="12"
          form:id="enquiry-form"
          required="first_name|last_name|email|code_regional|telephone_debut|telephone_fin|region|career"
          return="/thank-you"
          inline_errors="yes"

          recipients="yes"
          recipient_template="notification_career"
          recipient1="TEST1|myemail@host.com"
          recipient2="TEST2|myotheremail@gmail.com"
}
```

This is my select tag code

```
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Choose Recipients</label>
<select class="form-control" name="recipient_email" id="recipient_email">
        <option value=""></option>
        {freeform:recipients}
          <option value="{freeform:recipient_value}"{if freeform:recipient_selected}selected="selected"{/if}>{freeform:recipient_name}</option>
        {/freeform:recipients}
      </select>
                    {if freeform:error:region}
                      <strong><p class="red_error">{freeform:error:region}</p></strong>
                    {/if}
              </div>
```

In my Control Panel's structure, I did not enter any admin_notify because I guess dynamic recipients would override it. And my select tag has a name="recipient_email"...I think I really did everything but when I submit, still the page refresh and that's it =/

Thanks

Comment: I've also run into this issue on EE 2.9.2 and FF 3.2.2 - did you find a solution? notify_admin works by not recipients="yes"

Comment: I'm running into the same issue, find any solutions?